# Chi-square test of independence, what's the maximum number of rows we can have?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, count-data, group-differences

If I have a chi-square test of independence on a table with many rows, but only two columns, would this present a problem?

Comment: What kind of "problem" do you have in mind?

Comment: Suppose that I have people going into a concert and it ranges from $200$ to $400$ people a day. I want to see if a billboard being put up off the freeway would result in more people going. Hence, the billboard being put up is an indicator variable of $1$ or $0$. The exactly number of people who go are sorted in the rows of the table, and so the first row might be $202$, second, $213$, etc.  I have over 190 of these. Will the chi-square test of independence work here? Or should I combine rows together?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a chi-squared test would have any meaning for this situation.

Comment: A rejection in the usual chi-squared test could occur even when the means were the same for both (or the medians if you chose to compare medians, and so on). You could partition the chi-square into orthogonal polynomial components, the first of which would correspond to a comparison of means, but you could compare means (or size more generally) without doing that (you might use Mann-Whitney, or perhaps a t-test without equal variances, or a Poisson model, or some permutation test). However, perhaps the bigger issues are (i) the number of potential attendees changes from day to day, ...ctd

Comment: ctd ... so if you don't randomize the days the billboard was used (and have several periods when it was up and not up), the comparison will be confounded with other variables, and (ii) the effect of the billboard may last for some time after the billboard is not up, so you may need gaps between your recording periods

Answer (score 1):

A chi-square test of independence **will not work here**, it does not make any sense.  What you have is an (experimental) two-group comparison, one sample from days with billboard (see description in comments, was not included in post itself) and the other group for days without billboard.

As your number seems to be large, a simple t-test could work, but we would need more details to advice. As you have count data, a count data model would be a principled solution. But people going to concerts often arrive in groups, so the counts do probably not have a Poisson distribution. You could try negative binomial.